# default style for select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<select id="select">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>

<span id="red">red </span> <span id="default">default</span>

$("#red").click(function(){
    $("#select").css('background-color', 'red');
});

$("#default").click(function(){
    $("#select").css('background-color', 'white');
});
```

if i click RED then select is red. how can i set default style for select, against white?

Comment: Can you explain "set default style for select, against white" in more detail? I don't understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the property to reset the background color to its default:

```
$("#default").click(function(){
    $("#select").css('background-color', '');
});
```

For reference, see the [jQuery `.css()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2). Quote:

> Setting the value of a style property to an empty string — e.g.
>   `$('#mydiv').css('color', '')` — removes that property from an element
>   if it has already been directly applied, whether in the HTML style
>   attribute, through jQuery's .css() method, or through direct DOM
>   manipulation of the style property.